# Error at print statement in Python 3

Tags: python

All the questions I find on here don't quite answer my question.

I'm doing a tutorial on Python and he is using an older version of it. (pre 3.0)

Right now he is showing string indexing However, the syntax changed in Python so his code is invalid, here it is:

```
s = '<any string>'
print s[0]
```

It is suppose to print < but I get a syntax error. 
here is the error.

```
print name[0]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried all that I know to do this now but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Can someone explain where I could find the right answer or you could just tell me.

Comment: What error message do you get? What does it tell you?. It's not the string indexing that has changed!

Comment: When posting a question about an error, please always include the actual error. Preferably in unmodified form.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if I didn't include the actual error at first, I have now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with the indexing, but with the `print` statement.

[`print` is a function in `Python 3`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), whereas in `Python 2`, it was just a `statement`. You need to use it as such:

```
print(s[0])
```